# HTC XE turned itself off and won't turn back on

Tags: power-on, htc-sensation-xe

I charged my phone overnight for at least 6 hours. It was working fine when I checked my emails first thing this morning.

Then, the phone restarted itself (not uncommon!). Since then, I can't turn it on. I have taken the battery out and left it out for around 2 hours; it still won't turn on.

I have tried to turn it on in recovery  (holding the down volume button and the power on button) and still nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding the button down? When the phone is running, a single quick press on the power button will usually wake it up. When it is completely off, like due to the battery being removed, you often have to hold the button down for a short while.

You should also make sure it is charged using a wall charger. A completely depleted phone may not be able to charge from the USB port of a laptop.

Beyond that, I have seen cases where the power button wore out.